Using aws4 to sign a request and exclude the payload from being signed not working
I have a lambda behind an api gateway secured using aws_iam, I'm trying to give access to this api via signature v4 for 5min, during this time, the api could be called with different payloads each time.
To achieve this, I'm using aws4 to sign my url as follow:
const opts = {
  method: 'POST',
  host: '<myhostname>',
  path: '/path/to/resource',
  service: 'execute-api',
  region: 'my-region',
  headers: {
    'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
  },
};
const res = sign(opts);

I'm adding the header x-amz-content-sha256 with value UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD to tell aws not to sign the payload, as mentioned in the aws documentation:

Unsigned payload option – You include the literal string UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD when constructing a canonical request, and set the same value as the x-amz-content-sha256 header value when sending the request to Amazon S3.

However, I keep getting The String-to-Sign should have been when I call my endpoint with the authorization headers from the aws4.
Everything works fine if I include a fixed payload like:
const opts = {
  method: 'POST',
  host: '<myhostname>',
  path: '/path/to/resource',
  service: 'execute-api',
  region: 'my-region',
  body: '{"value": "dummyPayload"}',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};
const res = sign(opts);
A

m I missing something while authenticating ?

UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD is unique to S3.  It does not apply to API Gateway

Thanks @erik258 I doubted that since the documentation mention only s3. Do you know if there is a way to achieve what I'm willing to do with sig v4 ?

" I'm trying to give access to this api via signature v4 for 5min, during this time, the api could be called with different payloads each time"  One option is to assume a role and then pass those temporary credentials down to the user.  The minim expiration time is 15 minutes, but if you absolutely need it to stop working within 5 minutes, you can add time constraints with a session policy

If I understand correctly, the solution you suggested will only work if the end user is accessing my api via aws api. In my case, my end user will have the complete signed url and can use it either in his browser, or via some http client. If my understanding is correct, this solution will not work

Presigned URL is also accessing "via aws api".  You can make such calls from anywhere.  They will have to be properly signed to work, but you can make such a request from a browser or some other http client if properly signed.  And you're correct, you can't presign any requests except S3.  so The presign idea is right out.  The browser itself  can run the javascript SDK so in that case its fairly straightforward to make such requests

I created a new role that can only invoke the apigw, then used the assume role to assume that role as you suggested to have temporary credentials, then, used those credentials client side to generate a signed URL for the api calls, and all worked like a charm, thanks again @erik258
